# How to order citations by real appearence including in figures

Tags: floats, citing, sorting

I am trying to write text in LaTeX with multiple references while one of them is used in a figure caption. Figure is in a float environment, so in the LaTeX source file it is placed at a beginning of relevant section while in pdf it appears after few paragraphs of text. My problem is that text which is in LaTeX source file after the figure and in pdf before the figure contains some citations and their numbers should begin at [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlHS1.png). Instead, they begin at [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcaRG.png) and number [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlHS1.png) is used in figure caption, so it out of order in pdf.

It is possible to somehow convince LaTeX to number citations based on order of appearance in pdf, not in LaTeX source file? I know that I can move the figure in source file, but I am looking for more elegant solution.

Edit: here is a simplified example of a source code. Bibliography style is defined as \bibliographystyle{unsrt} in file bibliography.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[IL2]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[clip,trim={0cm 7cm 0cm 0cm}, width=10cm] {img/figure1}
    \caption[Figure 1]{Figure 1}
    \label{fig_1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[clip,trim={0cm 0cm 0cm 7cm}, width=9cm] {img/figure2}
    \caption[Figure 2]{Figure 2. Addapted from \cite{citD}}
    \label{fig_2}
\end{figure}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\cite{citA}, consectetur adipiscing elit\cite{citB}. 
Integer lobortis odio non mauris scelerisque, eget volutpat felis cursus.
Nulla sit amet lobortis justo, sit amet facilisis ipsum. Pellentesque in placerat nunc\cite{citC}. 
Praesent mauris nisl, tempus sit amet nibh in, eleifend porttitor odio. Pellentesque tortor erat, auctor nec nisi non, feugiat posuere nulla. Proin vitae blandit urna. 
Cras finibus suscipit justo ac fermentum\cite{citD}. Morbi volutpat vel mauris vel suscipit. 
Etiam pharetra, lorem non commodo pulvinar, quam nulla varius ante, non consectetur nulla lectus at ipsum. 
   Duis a mi vulputate, mollis odio sit amet, dapibus ipsum.
   \include{bibliography}
   \end{document}
```

This is how the pdf looks:
[image: First page of pdf]
[image: Second page of pdf]
[image: Third page of pdf]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: the order is order of  appearancxe in the output not in the source. You have shown no code but i would guess you have a `\cite` in a `\caption` thatappears in a list of figures _at the start_ so that cite appears early use `\caption[no cite here]{longer cpation with \cite{}}`